# How to recompile Ubuntu Toolchain?

Tags: 14.04, compiling, gcc

Where I can find environment description and build options that you use on build servers for Ubuntu Toolchain 4.1/4.7/4.9/etc?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebuild with following packages and repositories.

You need those packages:
    -

```
    - "build-essential"
    - "fakeroot"
    - "dpkg-dev"
    - "python-software-properties"
    - "software-properties-common"
    - "rsync"
    - "ubuntu-keyring"
    - "ubuntu-extras-keyring"
    - "debian-keyring"
    - "debian-ports-archive-keyring"
    - "debian-archive-keyring"
    - "emdebian-archive-keyring"
    - "ubuntu-cloudimage-keyring"
    - "ubuntu-cloud-keyring"
```

You should use those repositories:

```
- "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted universe"
- "deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted universe"
- "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe"
- "deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe"
```

And recompile:

```
apt-get build-dep -y gcc-4.9-multilib
apt-get source -y gcc-4.9-multilib

dpkg-source -x gcc-4.9_4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04.dsc
cd gcc-4.9-4.9.2
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b
```